# Tikz people in diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Do you know how to use tikz people here? It throws me an error.

> Credits to @Marmot

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows.blur,shapes.geometric,calc,fit}
\tikzset{database/.style={cylinder,aspect=2,draw,fill,shape border rotate=90,path picture={
\draw[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding
box.south west)$) in 
foreach \XX in {1,2,3}  {([yshift=-\XX*\y1/4]path picture bounding box.north west) 
arc(180:360:\x1/2 and 0.25*\x1/2)};
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={draw,align=center},local bounding box=Canada]
  \node[database,minimum size=3em,label={[name=DB]below:DB}] (db){};
  \node[draw=blue,anchor=north] (MT) at ([xshift=-9em]db.west) {Training \\ model};
  \node[draw=green!60!black,above=2em of MT] (PM)  {Predictive \\
  Model};
  \path (PM.north west) + (-3em,5em) (MT) + (0,-5em);
 \end{scope}
 \draw (Canada.south west) rectangle (Canada.north east) node[below
 left]{Recommendation Engine};
 \path let \p1=($(Canada.north)-(Canada.south)$) in 
 node[left=1em of Canada,minimum height=\y1,inner ysep=0pt,draw] (Client) {Client};
 \bob[shift={([xshift=-5em,yshift=-3em]Client.west)}]
 \begin{scope}[thick,-latex,nodes={fill=white,align=center}]
  \draw (Client.71) -| (db) node[pos=0.35]
  {user feedback\\ (ratings, clicks, watch, browsee)};
  \draw[green!60!black]  (db.west) -- ++(-2em,0) |- (PM) 
   node[pos=0.2]{New products};
  \draw[green!60!black]  (PM.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |- (Client.-70) 
   node[pos=0.2]{Recommended \\ Products};
  \draw[dashed,blue!80!black] (DB.south) -- ++ (0,-1.5em) -| (MT)
  node[pos=0.2]{User history};
  \draw[dashed,blue!80!black] (MT) -- (PM);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `\bob` is not a command, but `bob` is a node shape. The `tikzlings` and `tikzpeople` are a bit different in this regard. (There is the possibility to use `pic`s for the `tikzlings`, but in my previous answer I used another syntax which also works. Defining shapes is actually more effort than "just" defining `pic`s or commands, you can as Rmano about it. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadows.blur,shapes.geometric,calc,fit}
\tikzset{database/.style={cylinder,aspect=1,draw,fill,shape border rotate=90,path picture={
\draw[white] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding
box.south west)$) in 
foreach \XX in {1,2,3}  {([yshift=-\XX*\y1/4]path picture bounding box.north west) 
arc(180:360:\x1/2 and 0.25*\x1/2)};
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\tiny]
 \begin{scope}[nodes={draw,align=center},local bounding box=Canada]
  \node[database,minimum size=3em,label={[name=DB]below:DB}] (db){};
  \node[draw=blue,anchor=north] (MT) at ([xshift=-9em]db.west) {Training \\ model};
  \node[draw=green!60!black,above=2em of MT] (PM)  {Predictive \\
  Model};
  \path (PM.north west) + (-3.5em,5em) (MT) + (0,-5em) (db.east) +(1em,0);
 \end{scope}
 \draw (Canada.south west) rectangle (Canada.north east) node[below
 left]{Recommendation Engine};
 \path let \p1=($(Canada.north)-(Canada.south)$) in 
 node[left=1em of Canada,minimum height=\y1,inner ysep=0pt,draw] (Client) {Client};
 \node[bob,left=1.4em of Client,scale=2](Bob){};
 \begin{scope}[thick,-latex,nodes={fill=white,align=center}]
  \draw (Client.71) -| (db) node[pos=0.3]
  {user feedback\\ (ratings, clicks, watch, browsee)};
  \draw[green!60!black]  (db.west) -- ++(-2em,0) |- (PM) 
   node[pos=0.2]{New\\ products};
  \draw[green!60!black]  (PM.west) -- ++(-1em,0) |- (Client.-70) 
   node[pos=0.2]{Recommended \\ Products};
  \draw[dashed,blue!80!black] (DB.south) -- ++ (0,-1.5em) -| (MT)
  node[pos=0.2]{User history};
  \draw[dashed,blue!80!black] (MT) -- (PM);
  \draw[latex-latex] (Bob.east) -- (Bob.east-|Client.west);
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome!!! Thank you very much for the explanation. One last thing, the 'R' from the word Recommended Products is interjecting itself with the box. Could you fix it?

Comment: @Delan You're welcome! Fixed it. AFAIK the only ways these collisions can be avoided fully automatically are either to make the code more complicated, or to employ [positioning plus](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf), which however is not on CTAN.

Comment: "collisions can be avoided fully automatically": this should apply to each tikZ pictue, although I know it's hard

Comment: For the arrow between client and bob `\draw[blue] (Client) -- (bob)` but it does not work

Comment: @Delan For me it immediately worked. I updated this and the other answer.